# requireJS fails to load my first file (typescript)

Tags: requirejs, typescript

This is very weird because it was all working Friday, and now it doesn't. When my program first starts, it fails on the very first require with "Module name "../common/windward" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded"

test-layout.html:

```
<script src="../../libs/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../libs/es6-promise.js"></script>
<script data-main="test-layout.js" src="../../libs/require.js"></script>
```

test-layout.js:

```
var windward = require('../common/windward');
```

The requireJS manual wants the first require to be:

```
require(['foo'], function (foo) {
    //foo is now loaded.
});
```

However, this is the way the typescript compiler creates the .js file (for amd). And it worked 3 days ago.

Is there something else I need to do to get requireJS started?

Answer (score 2):

> this is the way the typescript compiler creates the .js file (for amd).

No. It should generate:

```
define(["require", "exports", "../common/windward"], function(require, exports, windward) {
});
```

Something seems to be calling `--module commonjs` in your pipeline.